# Connect to different port using MySql Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, command-line, port

By default I am being connected to port 3309.I need to connect to port 3307.How do I do that?

Answer (score 92):

Use `-P` parameter, like this:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u user_name -p database_name
```

Important: if you connecting to `localhost` - use `-h 127.0.0.1`, NOT `localhost`, because MySQL will connect by file socket, not by TCP

Comment: mysql> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p sch_rel_122718;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p sch_rel_122718' at line 1.

I even ommited the mysql in the start but the to no avail.

Comment: This message means that you are successfully connected to database. 

Suppose you are trying to load some SQL from file, like this:

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p sch_rel_122718 < file.sql

The error is in the file.sql. Show the file, I will help.

PS: is `sch_rel_122718` the database name?

Comment: Yes I am connected to the database but to port 3309 because when I execute "show databases" it displays the databases of that port.and yes sch_rel_122718 is the name of the database which exists in port 3307.

Comment: Are you specify -h 127.0.0.1, NOT -h localhost?

Comment: Yup -h 127.0.0.1 no localhost

Comment: Please run commands and copy output:
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p (when connect type: show databases)
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3309 -u root -p (when connect type: show databases)

Answer (score 2):

From command line, assuming you are on the same host, have you tried :

```
mysql --user root --password (mypassword) --host=localhost --port=33061
```

In server name specify custom port when not using default one (you can imply it only when is the standard mysql port 3306)

$servername = "localhost:33061";

Answer (score 2):

you can use -P **(uppercase)** or --port=portnumber
sample

```
mysql -u root -P 13306 -p databasename
```

or

```
mysql -u root --port=13306 -p databasename
```

Answer (score 1):

for *nix client use `--host=127.0.0.1` instead of localhost

`mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 -u root -pdb_passwd db_name`

> Only connection options that are relevant to the selected transport protocol are used or checked. Other connection options are ignored. For example, with --host=localhost on Unix, the client attempts to connect to the local server using a Unix socket file, even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a TCP/IP port number.

> To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1 (instead of localhost), or the IP address or name of the local server.

Comment: FYI: For this type of answer, you should provide an example... because sometimes user's won't fully understand, and voters will pick other answers...

Comment: example has been provided. please review

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command changing your details.
after that MySQL requests the password for the connection, then enter the password.

```sql
mysql --user=user1  --host=127.16.38.1 --port=25060 -p
```

especially consider about -p and double Hyphen --

Answer (score 0):

I am giving simple way, one liner which summarizes.

`mysql -u root -p --port=3316` `// I have MySQL port 3316, instead of default 3306`

If the `--port=3316` is not provided, then `MySQL Cli protocol` will try with the default port, without asking.

For any other user

`mysql -u anotheruser -p --port=3316`